# Generic method for inserting JSON data in SQLite Database (using Volley)

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, hashmap

Im new to Volley (and SQLite) and trying to figure out how I can store the response (which is an JSON Array) in a SQLite Table?

As for now I loop through the Array to make separate JSON Objects, and put their values in a model.

My first though was to make 'insert(MyModel)' method in my SQLite database but it doesnt feel generic enough. (If I have a model folder with over 20+ different models which means I need to create a new insert method for each Model which would result in long and messy code).

Am I completely wrong in how I think or where should I head next? I tried to make a generic method that takes in a HashMap but I didnt get it to work.

Any tips?

API Sample:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "sample string 1",
    "SomeSampleBoolean": true,
    "Icon": "sample string 2",
    "ProjectID": 3,
  },
  {
    "Name": "sample string 1",
    "SomeSampleBoolean": false,
    "Icon": "sample string 2",
    "ProjectID": 4,
  }
]
```